# Is Nonduality considered a topic for Philosophy SE

Tags: support

There is currently no [nonduality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonduality) tag and no questions about it, except one from 2015 asking if it was appropriate for the Site.

Lack of interest? Or not on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

There have been quite a few questions about and answers based on nonduality which may not bear this tag. We also had a quite active user who kind of lobbied for it under the name of perennial philosophy.

The reception was not overwhelmingly positive due to a hue of zealotry in his posts telling everyone else they just wouldn't understand the necessary truth of it, not because of the content as such.

That said, I'd love to see more variety of philosophical approaches being asked about and do not see anything against being on topic nor an inherent lack of interest.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a tag for perennial-philosophy either. Is there a way for me to find these posts?

Comment: Search for "perennial philosophy", the now deleted user shows as user20253.